# Fill a column's Values based on another column values in the same row

Tags: mysql

```
capacity  Comment

1.0
1.7
7.2
9.9
10.0
```

what i want to do is, i want to auto full comment value based on capacity value.

**if capacity value is 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5.... (all decimals up to 1.9) i want to fill comment values as "low"**

so that it will look like this

```
capacity  Comment

1.0        low
1.7        low  
7.2        average
9.9        fine
INTEL      great
```

Hope you understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this has to be done with MySQL as opposed to doing it with PHP/ASP...etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression to do so:

```
UPDATE Tablename
SET Comment = CASE 
                WHEN capacity >= 1.0 AND Capacity <= 1.9 THEN 'low'
                WHEN ... THEN 'average' -- Put the condition for the average 
                ... 
              END;
```

- Put in each `WHEN` clause, the condition for each level.
- Don't forget the `ELSE` clause, because it has `NULL` as the default value if you didn't defined one.

Comment: but when i tried to do this :( nothing happens.. it is changing to green mark and when i refresh the page, it again changes to default

Comment: bro when i tried this ` WHEN capacity = 7.0 THEN 'AVG' ` it is showing me error

Comment: @user2373405 - Can you please me the exact query you tried that gave you the error? and what is that error? Please edit your question and add these details to it, so that I can address the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user2373405 - Are you sure you entered this value as `10.0` not quoted with two '`'?

Comment: @user2373405 - It should work fine, see [**this sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adb50/1) . Can you please update this demo and show me that issue in this demo with the actual data that you tried?

Comment: sorry bro it really didn't work for me. if possible can you update your answer with the query i have to use in case of equal to.

Comment: @Alya'aGamal yes it is working for numbers and decimals. but not for letters. check my question (have just updated it) added INTEL at last row.

Comment: didn't work :( query ran successfully. but showed 0 rows affected :(

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cf19nm64e please check this. some thing went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Use update with an If maybe?

Like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET comment = IF (capacity < 2, 'low', IF(capacity < 8, 'average').... )
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') )' at line 2 #ERROR

Comment: yeah its not a complete example, god forbid you have to alter and type anything yourself, sorry about that. the ... was meant to indicate you need to take this shell of an example and work with it a bit to get a final answer. Next time I will be sure only to post totally complete answers for you.